# Prove that any ring map $\sigma: R \rightarrow S$ induces an injective homomorphism of rings: $R/\sigma^{-1}(I) \rightarrow S/I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I \subset S$ be any ideal. Prove that any ring map $\sigma: R \rightarrow S$ induces an injective homomorphism of rings: $R/\sigma^{-1}(I) \rightarrow S/I$. Conclude that if $I$ is prime, so is $\sigma^{-1}(I)$.

I'm not sure how to deal with the elements in quotient rings so not sure how to say that the kernel is trivial...Anyone would can help me formulate this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the canonical map $\pi\colon S\to S/I$; then $\pi\circ\sigma$ is a ring homomorphism $\pi\circ\sigma\colon R\to S/I$, with kernel
$$
\ker(\pi\circ\sigma)=\sigma^{-1}(I)
$$
(it's an easy verification).

*Every* ring homomorphism $\alpha\colon A\to B$ induces an injective ring homomorphism $A/\ker\alpha\to B$ (standard homomorphism theorem).